# Is Cairo dock 2.4 fully compatible with Intel i965?

Tags: 11.04, intel-graphics

Well the title sums up my question. Will it work on my card? If it helps Unity 3D works perfectly.

Comment: You could also try installing it, see if it works and then answer your own question and mark it as the right answer. Your question gets answered, plus you make some points ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Cairo dock with Open GL is fully compatible with the i965 video csrd from intel just search for it in the Ubuntu Software Center and click on the install button. When Ubuntu Software Center is done with the installation, hit the 'super' key and type 'Cairo dock' and click on the 'Cairo dock with Open GL' and choose 'yes' when prompted.
There it is voila!

Answer (score 1):

As unity is playing ball, it'd be fair to say that cairo will to.